# How to load a local assembly in Jupyter-Notebooks/C#

Tags: c#, .net, jupyter-notebook, .net-assembly

Using **Jupyter-Notebooks**
(the *Standard/Browser version* or the *VSCode extension*)
how can I load a .net (5.x) Assembly?
(should be something like: #r "System.Windows.Forms")

for example to do something like:

> ```
> using System.Windows.Forms
> System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( "Hello ppl!!!" )
> ```